# I got following error when I compile following program for xml to excel to conversion

Tags: java, eclipse

Though I import all packages it can't work. I am new in java.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
>   at demo.ReadAndPrintXMLFile.main(ReadAndPrintXMLFile.java:101) Caused
>   by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.

```
package demo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class ReadAndPrintXMLFile {
    private static XSSFWorkbook workbook;

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        ArrayList<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lastNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ages = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("D:/amit/book.xml"));

            // normalize text representation
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element of the doc is :\" "+ doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName() + "\"");
            NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
            int totalPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();
            System.out.println("Total no of people : " + totalPersons);
            for (int s = 0; s < listOfPersons.getLength(); s++) 
            {
                Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
                if (firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
                {
                    Element firstPersonElement = (Element) firstPersonNode;
                    NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("first");
                    Element firstNameElement = (Element) firstNameList.item(0);
                    NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
                    System.out.println("First Name : "+ ((Node) textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                    firstNames.add(((Node) textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                    NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("last");
                    Element lastNameElement = (Element) lastNameList.item(0);
                    NodeList textLNList = lastNameElement.getChildNodes();
                    System.out.println("Last Name : "+ ((Node) textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                    lastNames.add(((Node) textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                    NodeList ageList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("age");
                    Element ageElement = (Element) ageList.item(0);
                    NodeList textAgeList = ageElement.getChildNodes();
                    System.out.println("Age : "+ ((Node) textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                    ages.add(((Node) textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                }// end of if clause

            }// end of for loop with s var
            for(String firstName:firstNames)
            {
                System.out.println("firstName : "+firstName);
            }
            for(String lastName:lastNames)
            {
                System.out.println("lastName : "+lastName);
            }
            for(String age:ages)
            {
                System.out.println("age : "+age);
            }

        } 
        catch (SAXParseException err) 
        {
            System.out.println("** Parsing error" + ", line "+ err.getLineNumber() + ", uri " + err.getSystemId());
            System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (SAXException e) 
        {
            Exception x = e.getException();
            ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (Throwable t) 
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");

        Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
        for(int i=0;i<firstNames.size();i++)
        {
            data.put(i+"",new Object[]{firstNames.get(i),lastNames.get(i),ages.get(i)});
        }
        Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                if (obj instanceof Date)
                    cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof Boolean)
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof Double)
                    cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/amit/book1.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }// end of main
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dependency to `org.apache.commons.collections4`. This might be because of your other dependencies (which should have the collections4 dependency in theirs, but apparently there is still some sort of error).

You can try to add the JAR to the path, or if you use any build tools (Maven, Gradle, Ivy, etc.) you can add it to the dependencies list. Try and add this dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1

Comment: I added that jar already and build path but it still showing the same error.It just showing me plane output in eclipse but it is not creating the excel file which I want.

Comment: Have a look here and try to interpret in what you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java. Basically, you are getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` which is different than `ClassNotFoundError`, but it signifies that `ListValuedMap` is not present at runtime, but is at compile time.

Comment: Root element of the doc is :" book"
Total no of people : 3
First Name : hussain
Last Name : hussain
Age : 21
First Name : akhtar
Last Name : akhtar
Age : 22
First Name : wahid
Last Name : wahid
Age : 23
firstName : hussain
firstName : akhtar
firstName : wahid
lastName : hussain
lastName : akhtar
lastName : wahid
age : 21
age : 22
age : 23 and remaining output is I am mentioning in following comment

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
 at demo.ReadAndPrintXMLFile.main(ReadAndPrintXMLFile.java:101)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)